# Komma vor *besonders*, wenn es keinen Einschub, kein Aufzählungsglied und keinen Nebensatz einführt?

Tags: comma

Betrachten wir den folgenden Satz:

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur besonders bei der Entwicklung *großer* Systeme.

Hier wird die "Entwicklung *großer* Systeme" betont (ist also nicht als Neben- sondern als Hauptinformation gedacht).

Kommt ein Komma vor "besonders"? Warum oder warum nicht?

Answer (score 3):

Bei einer nachgestellten Erläuterung wird nach [§77.4](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html) der amtlichen Regeln ein Komma gesetzt.

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur**,** besonders bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme

Answer (score 2):

Beide Sätze

1)

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur besonders bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme.

und

2)

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur, besonders bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme.

sind korrekt, haben aber eine andere grammatische Struktur:

1) ist eine **Inversion** (Umstellung) des Satzes

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist besonders bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.

und in 2) handelt es sich um eine **nachträgliche Erläuterung**.

Stilistisch ist die Inversion hier allerdings auffällig und wirkt unmotiviert. Gefälliger wäre wohl

> Insbesondere bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.

Answer (score 1):

Hier ist kein Komma notwendig, da es sich nicht um eine Erläuterung, sondern um einen Bestandteil des eigentlichen Satzes handelt.

Der Unterschied ist folgender:

**Nachgestellte Erläuterung:**

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur, besonders bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme.

Daraus kann man zwei Schlüsse ziehen:

1. Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.
2. Besonders bei der Entwicklung *großer* Systeme ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sich ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.

**Eigener Bestandteil:**

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur besonders bei der Entwicklung *großer* Systeme.

Hier geht es in erster Linie um den zweiten Schluss von oben, weniger um den ersten. Der Unterschied ist ein gradueller, aber geht klar mit unterschiedlicher Betonung in beiden Fällen hervor. Wenn es als eigener Bestandteil gedacht ist, ist eine Umstellung allerdings deutlich schöner:

> Besonders bei der Entwicklung *großer* Systeme ist die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.

oder

> Die Unterscheidung zwischen Blackbox- und Whitebox-Sicht ist besonders bei der Entwicklung *großer* Systeme ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur.

Answer (score 0):

Aufzählung. A comma can virtually always be explained conceptually as delineating items in a listing, eventually with elision of repetitive parts within the items (such as can be seen above at "Blackbox- ... -Sicht"). Therefore it's perhaps not very good style, but speech is just lists of words, if you will, and pragmatism trumps style.

> ... ist ein Merkmal für ordentliche Softwarearchitektur [und ist] besonders [ein Merkmal [für...]] bei der Entwicklung großer Systeme.

The elision is pragmatic, so it's ambiguous to what PoS *besonders* applies and my bracketing is just hypothetical.

Thus, if *große Systeme* is to be emphasized, it should read "bei der Entwicklung besonders großer Systeme". Since *besonders* might sound negative if it implies *extraordinary*, then *hinreichend* may be chosen, though it sounds cliched. But that changes the original meaning to much, so in conclusion it seems obvious that in fact "ordentliche Systeme" is emphatic.